# DebugKit.ToolbarComponent could not be found

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu-14.04, cakephp-2.5

I followed the instruction in the README.md file in the directory DebugKit. But when I add this line I am getting this error above but when i comment out the line in the AppController then everything is ok and i'm getting "DebugKit plugin is present"

```php
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
}
```

does anyone know how can i smooth this error out?

I have ubuntu 14.10 CakePHP 2.5

Comment: Ok it is done now. The error in my case was that I pasted in the wrapped folder and not the contents of the folder in this folder "DebugKit" I had just to match the path in the error to my path :)

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/issues/543

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have

```
\DebugKit
      \Controller
            \Component
                  \ToolbarComponent.php
```

In case you don't have this directory (which was the case for me)
then

```
cd Plugin/DebugKit
sudo mkdir Controller
sudo mkdir Component
sudo gedit ToolbarComponent.php
```

And then the text editor will pop up and just put the code below

```
<?php
class ToolbarComponent extends Component {

}
```